# How is the location of this point derived?

Tags: linear-model, regularization

Given a vector $\mathbf{w_{\theta}}$ which is normal to the orange line:

[image]

And two point $\mathbf{x}$ how is $\mathbf{x_p}$ derived? I understand that the vector $\mathbf{w_{\theta}}$ is the vector that has a direction that is the same as a dotted line, but why does the inner product of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{w_{\theta}}$ determine the magnitude of the vector?

[image]

The images above are from [A New Angle on L2 Regularization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.11186.pdf)